# how to supply multi-line commands to sshpass for a specific case using 'if-fi' in shell

Tags: shell, ubuntu, ssh, sshpass

```
 sshpass -p "123456789" ssh -T jadams@192.168.1.85 <<'EOSSH'
    if [-d "$HOME/ajith/apache-tomcat-7.0.63/webapps/$tag_version" ] then
          sh $HOME/ajith/apache-tomcat-7.0.63/bin/shutdown.sh &&
          rm -rf  $HOME/ajith/apache-tomcat-7.0.63/webapps/$tag_version && 
          mkdir $HOME/ajith/apache-tomcat-7.0.63/webapps/$tag_version
    fi
    EOSSH
```

This code above is a part of the shell script which I am using

### The Problem :

The problem I am facing is that I am trying to execute set of commands to deploy a webapp on a remote tomcat server and the concern of my interest is that I want to be able to execute multi-line commands using sshpass as above but I am getting error as below:

*-bash: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file*

I am searching for a working example for this use-case or any assistance relevant would be of great help.

I have tried many examples from the google search results and I am unable to do it

Comment: The terminating word **must not** have leading or trailing whitespace. Also, use `$(...)` instead of backticks, and put the ending `)` on the line after `EOSSH`

Comment: Also , you need a space between `[` and `-d`

Comment: Glenn thanks for reply  ,` ` was just a formatting-typo in stackoverflow window .And can you just give me modified code with your inputs.?

Comment: Thanks glenn and also thanks for downvoting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue using the below mentioned code and serve my
purpose :

```
sshpass -p "password" ssh $server_name@$server_ip bash -c "'
    if [ -d "/home/motish/ajith/apache-tomcat-7.0.63/webapps/$tag_version" ]; then
        rm -rf /home/motish/ajith/apache-tomcat-7.0.63/webapps/$tag_version;
        mkdir /home/motish/ajith/apache-tomcat-7.0.63/webapps/$tag_version;
    fi
    else
        mkdir /home/motish/ajith/apache-tomcat-7.0.63/webapps/$tag_version;
    exit;
    '"
```